# PHP form with two <select> variable passing as one

Tags: php, forms

i have a form, say a.php, with

```
<select 1>var1...</select>
<select 2>var2...</select>
```

for some reason, i really want to pass those two variables as just one as

```
a.php?a=var1_var2
```

i don't know how to make it work.

thanks a lot.

Comment: bind a javascript event before submitting the form that concatenates them both and submits the form

Answer (score 1):

Just pass them individually and later concatenate to your desired valued.

```
<?php
var a = $_GET["var1"].$_GET["var2"];
?>
```

and call as:

```
a.php?var1=val1&var2=val2
```

Comment: the problem is i don't want var1 or var2 got passed

Comment: i only want 1 variable for those two selects for some special reason

Comment: Not sure why you would want this, but in that case you would need to use JavaScript to prepare the url from client side and then send that to server side by generating appropriate server url.

Comment: i have form call a.php with 3 parameters. i am able to use the following rewrite rule, and a_b.htm/c does work.

{ RewriteRule ^(.*)_([^]+).htm/([0-9.]+)$ a.php?f=$1&t=$2&amt_from=$3 [NC] } 

however, my problem is when the user click a sumit button on the form, i still see 
a.php?f=$1&t=$2&amt_from=$3

how to fix that?